# Sitecore Scheduled Tasks and Dependency Injection

Tags: sitecore-api

I am using sitecore workflow action in order to execute method, but the DI inject services not working, what i have to do to solve this issue ?

EX:

basiclly i have work flow that will call ResendAction to send some informations, and in this class i am using DI to inject some services , but the DI not working with this kind of sitecore background tasks, and i need to keep using DI to inject any service i need

```
public class ResendAction
{
    private readonly IRfiTasksHandler _rfiTasksHandler;

    public ResendAction(IRfiTasksHandler rfiTasksHandler)
    {
        _rfiTasksHandler = rfiTasksHandler
    }

    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {

    }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you give more information - show us what you have done already? (code, Sitecore version, ....)

Comment: @Gatogordo Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore DI will only resolve your instances in controllers and in pipelines where `resolve=true` is set.

```
<processor type="Foo.BarProcessor, Foo" resolve="true" />
```

You are going to have to new that up yourself.

```
private readonly IRfiTasksHandler _rfiTasksHandler;

public ResendAction()
{
    _rfiTasksHandler = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRfiTasksHandler>();
}

public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
{

}
```

If you're not using MVC or if you're in a Scheduled Task or otherwise outside page context, you can use the Service Locator code below to resolve it.

```
_rfiTasksHandler = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRfiTasksHandler>();
```

Comment: yes you are right , DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRfiTasksHandler>(); solved the issue